# Jenkins jobs disappeared from GUI, but are still present on the disk

Tags: jenkins

I had 2 folders containing several jobs and a lot of others jobs placed directly in the Jenkins jobs root.

I was the only one using the 2 folders, the rest of my colleagues only used the jobs in the root.

I haven't accessed Jenkins for 2 weeks. Today, when I logged in, the 2 folders containing my jobs were gone. The root jobs are still present.

On the disk the jobs are still present. I can find the configuration, the builds etc.

What could be the cause? My colleagues say they haven't touched my folders. No related errors in the jenkins log. All my plugins are still enabled. Indeed, many have updates available, but I guess it shouldn't matter. Also, if any problems were related to one of the jobs, why is the whole folders not showing up? I would expect only the jobs inside folders not showing up.

Any ideas how to approach this and recover my jobs?

Comment: Restore from a backup.

Comment: I assume I could only take my jobs from the backup, as my colleagues might have recently modified their jobs, but still, my jobs are there, on the server's disk, it's just that Jenkins doesn't load / show them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did someone uninstall the [folders plug-in](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-folder)?
2. Have you tried [reloading configuration from disk](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/209691677-What-does-Reload-Configuration-from-Disk-do-)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the folders plugin is enabled and reloading configuration from disk didn't help.

Comment: Since the jobs are just config.xml files - create a new job in a folder and compare the config.xml - if this shows nothing strange - try copying the zombie config.xml over the newly created config.xml (note that you will need to reload config from disk to get jenkins to pick up your change)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. indeed, config.xml files are missing for the missing jobs.. I assume that the backup is the only solution now. I don't understand what happened.